# What is causing these elements/artifacts to be rendered as shown?

Tags: chrome-for-android, developer-options

[image: Screenshot]

My wife changed my minimum width recently, but this hasn't broken browser rendering before in any of our previous devices.  Any ideas?

Comment: Clear the browser cache and reload page.

Comment: @Robert Did not fix the issue